# WCF DataContract Attribute

Tags: wcf

I have a question about the `[DataContract]` attribute.

I have written my code like below: here I am not using `[DataContract]` attribute for my test class.

```
    class test
    {
      [Datamember]
       public string Strproperty
        {
          get;
          set;
        }
       [Datamemer]
       public string Strproperty2
        {
          get;
          set;
        }
    }


 class checktotal:Iservice
    {
    public string testmethod(test obj)
       {
           return obj.Strproperty+Strproperty2;
       }
    }
```

For that I am sending data from client I am getting the values correctly.

Here is it necessary to use `[DataContract]` attribute for that test class?

If I removed `[Datamember]` for test class property is getting error while sending from client. But I am not getting any errors even if I am not using the `[DataContract]` attribute.

Please give me a brief explanation with example so that I can understand when to give that attribute and when do not give that attribute.

Thanks,
Satya Pratap.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataContractSerializer` can deal with classes that do not have the `DataContract` attribute if they provide a default constructor.  See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681329.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As of .NET 3.5 **Service Pack 1**, you can omit (not use) the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes. If you do that, then the `DataContractSerializer` in WCF will behave just like the XML serializer - it will serialize all public properties only.

I prefer to use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` explicitly anyway - it gives me the opportunity to specify options (like the data contract's XML namespace, the order of the `[DataMember]`) and it lets me e.g. also exclude certain properties from serialization.

As soon as you start using `[DataMember]` on one property, then **only** those properties decorated with a `[DataMember]` will be looked at for the WCF serialization.

Comment: you mean can we mention that class with [DataContractSerializer] attribute? Explain it little bit briefly.I am using .net 4.0 framework.

Comment: @Balu: **EITHER** you use **nothing at all** -> then WCF's DataContractSerializer works like XmlSerializer; **OR THEN** you use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` everywhere in your class. Pick one. You cannot mix the two approaches.